# Apostrophe 's' question

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Which is correct

Option A: The university should be the students' main community.
(with apostrophe)

or

Option B: The university should be the students main community.
(no apostrophe)

Answer (score 1):

Option A is correct and places the apostrophe in the position to indicate plural possessive. There are multiple students and the community belongs to them.

Option B doesn’t make sense.

If you’d placed the apostrophe thusly:

*[...] the student’s main community.*

This would indicate a singular possessive. There is one student and the community belongs to them.

Comment: Thank you Arkhem, your reasoning makes perfect sense. Your response has been very helpful.

Comment: Question not of ELU standard.